# How to save user last login date if he was logged in with external login provider using ASP .Net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I've extended `AspNetUser` class with `LastLoginDate` property to remember each time user makes login.

```
public sealed partial class User : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>, IUser<int>, IDatabaseEntity
{
    ...
    public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }   
}
```

Loging works fine each time user makes usual login using email and password as login credentials. In `AccountController` I have my login action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    ...
    var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe);

    if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(email);
        UserManager.RememberLoginDate(user);  
        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
    }

    ...
}
```

`RememberLoginDate` is just an extension methods which basically just sets current time to user `LastLoginDate`  property:

```
public static IdentityResult RememberLoginDate(this ApplicationUserManager manager, User user)
{
     user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;;
     return manager.Update(user);
}
```

But when I do external login like below:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string provider)
{
     var loginInfo = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();
     if (loginInfo == null)
          return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFail");

     // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
     var result = SignInManager.ExternalSignIn(loginInfo);
     if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
          return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

     if (result == SignInStatus.Failure)
     {
          return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation" ...) 
     }

     ...
}
```

How can I log user login date in this case? I have no info about the user such as `email` or `Id` to get him with `UserManager` at this point. I've already tried: `User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()` to get user `Id` after `SignInManager.ExternalSignIn(loginInfo)` but it is not updated after login, it still is `default(int)` - `0`. `SignInStatus` is just an `enum` with no additional info about the logged user and use `ExternalLoginInfo.Email` is also not an option because this email can be different from user's actual registered email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login)` to pull your user back via the provider and key - this is how the SignInManager itself works.